# Particle Disintegration Range of Angles (Landau& Lifshitz)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics

In the particle disintegration problem in the book by Landau and Lifshitz (pg 44 question 3), it is asked to find the range for $\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$, where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the angles between the angles $\theta_1$ and  $\theta_2$ (angles between the velocity of the com frame with respect to the lab frame ($V$) and the velocity of each particle in the lab frame ($v_{10}$ and $v_{20}$. Geometrically I can interpret the ranges however I cannot show them in the formula for $\tan\theta$. So far I got to

$$\tan\theta_1=\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\dfrac{V}{v_{10}}+v_{10}\cos\theta_0}$$

$$\tan\theta_2=\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{\dfrac{V}{v_{20}}-v_{20}\cos\theta_0}$$

Could someone help me figure out the ranges from here?

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $\theta_0$ and set to zero to find the stationary points.

Comment: Please use MathJax when typesetting math.

Comment: I switched to the MathJax and elaborated the question a bit more, please see the current version.